# Android Video and Audio Output

Tags: android

Is it possible in android to capture the screen image and any playing audio file? I have done some searches but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do these help?
[Capture android screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089383/android-screen-capture-problem) and [audio recording in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499474/audio-recording-in-android)

Comment: The video link does help, as it explains I cant without rooting. The second doesnt quite help, as I dont wish to record/capture an internal source, but whatever sound the device is outputing. I assume again that this is not possible without rooting? 

Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry should have accepted this answer, somehow I missed it. Many apologies

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to catch a video your application is playing, then the answer is not using java. see answers to my question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155292/get-current-frame-from-android-mediaplayer)

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to capture just my app, but any. Thanks for the help anyway, I should have been specific

Comment: The question is specific, the title is misleading. :)